# How Can I check if logged in user profile information is updated in django models

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project in Django where I have a Profile Model with a Foreign Key field (OneToOne Relationship with User Model) called applicant and a status field which is set to 'Update' at default. Other fields like surname and othernames are also included in the Profile Model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
othernames = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Update', null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.profilestatus = 'Updated'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.applicant.username}-Profile'
```

I want the system to check every logged in user if their profile information are not Updated, they should be redirected to the Profile Update page to update their profile first else they should be redirected to view their updated profile.

```
def index(request):

user = request.user.is_authenticated

if request.user.is_authenticated and Profile.objects.get(applicant=user, status= 'Update'):
    
    
    
    return redirect('user-profile-update')
else:
    return redirect('user-profile')

context = {
    'check_profile_update':check_profile_update,
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

I have ModelForm with a save method with automatically updates the satus field in Profile Model to Updated any time a user updates his or her profile information.

The issue is anytime I run the app error says 'Profile matching query does not exist.'

Someone should kindly help me on the best way of solving this issue.
In fact, how can I create an instance of the logged in user so I can check the user profile update status in model?
Thanks

Comment: You need to create a `Profile` instance for the particular `User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**
`user = request.user.is_authenticated` makes the variable `user = True`, so when you use it in
`if request.user.is_authenticated and Profile.objects.get(applicant=user, status= 'Update'):`,
you are really doing the following:
`if request.user.is_authenticated and Profile.objects.get(applicant=True, status= 'Update'):`
So of course there will be no matches since no applicant equals `True`.

**The Solution**
Change the two lines to:

```py
user = request.user    # Now user equals the actual user
if user.is_authenticated and Profile.objects.get(applicant=user, status= 'Update'):
```

**On another note:**
I hesitate to use a `get` query without putting it in a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) statement so that you can handle what should happen if a `Profile` is **not** found:

```py
user = request.user    # Now user equals the actual user
if user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(applicant=user, status= 'Update')
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        # Code to handle what happens if a Profile is NOT found
        # Maybe redirect to a page not found
        # or maybe redirect to a page to create an applicant?
```

**EDIT**

```py
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(applicant=user)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            print("Profile Does Not Exist")
            # Redirect to a Profile creating page?
        else:
            if profile.status == 'Update':
                return redirect('user-profile-update')
            else:
                return redirect('user-profile')
    
context = {
    'check_profile_update':check_profile_update,
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

**Edit 2**
As per your comment, the final working version is then:

```py
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(applicant=user)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            print("Profile Does Not Exist")
            # Redirect to a Profile creating page?
        else:
            if profile.surname == None:
                return redirect('user-profile-update')
            else:
                return redirect('user-profile')
    
context = {
    'check_profile_update':check_profile_update,
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks for your kind answer. One thing is that the solution you provided does not work as expected even when a user profile is not yet updated, the system does not  redirect him or her to the user-update page for him or her to update his page, rather it is directs to user-profile page (profile page)

Comment: I edited the answer, @apollos but I'm not sure if this is what you want.  Best of luck.

Comment: I edited my answer, @apollos though I'm not sure why the previous one did not work.  Anyway, I'm glad you got it to work!